# nginx rewrite only specific servername to https

Tags: nginx, rewrite, https, ubuntu-11.04

It's about two subdomains. The first one (www) should be accessed via http. The second one (cloud) should be accessed via https.

These are the relevant parts of my entries:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name cloud.example.de;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;  # enforce https
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name cloud.example.de;
        root /home/user/web/cloud;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.de;
        root /home/user/web/cms;

        #etc.
}
```

When I now call http://cloud.example.de I am redirected to https://cloud.example.de, fine.
But when I call http://www.example.de I am also redirected, to https://www.example.de, which leads me to the content of cloud.example.com, because this is the only servername set as used by port 443. 
 
There is no entry in the access-log of the www-subdomain.
There is another subdomain pointing to a phpPgAdmin. This I can access as normal, it's not rewritten.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name pgsql.example.de;
        root /home/user/web/phppgadmin;

        #etc
}
```

What is missing? **The rewrite should be only done if the servername matches cloud.example.de**. 
And is there a relevance in the order of the server entries or does it not matter?

Using nginx 0.8.54 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sample config that you provide looks about right, and I doubt it would work as you describe (you probably made too many changes when trying to simplify it).

Are you getting wrong redirects in something like `curl`, or only in the browser?  I've dealt with cases where `permanent` is permanently cached in Mozilla (e.g. from a prior `nginx.conf`), without any way to invalidate a single `301` cache entry, so, are you sure it's not a cache issue?

In any case, you could also try using `if` to make the redirects conditional (perhaps the first server gets chosen as the default server):

```
    if ($host = "cloud.example.de") {
            rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? redirect;
    }
    return 403;
```

Or, another option,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name cloud.example.de;
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? redirect;
    }
    root /home/user/web/cloud;
}
```

And try `curl -v` to make sure you're seeing what is there.

Comment: Seems it's really a browserrelated issue. I now tried your second option, it works fine in chromium and new profile in firefox. I cleared the cache in my default profile but it keeps redirecting me...but thats nothing related to nginx. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think you have to go as far as creating a new profile.  The issue is that Shift-Refresh doesn't work to clear the `301` page from cache, unlike it does for all other pages.  I stopped using `301` `permanent` for this reason; most of my redirects are now `302` `redirect`.  Another way to avoid a stale `301` is append `?21T0911` to the URL, where "21T0911" is something like the current date/time.